# Could you add a contract address in place of a library address when editing the bytecode before deplyment?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, library

After compiling a contract that uses a library it is necessary to go into the compile contract bytecode and remove a piece that looks something like "_________library__address______" and replace it with the deployed library address.

Tools like Remix automatically add this now for testing.

My question is: Since a library is just a type of contract, could I add a contract address instead of a library address to the bytecode? (and suffer whatever consequences to the functionality of the contract)

I am trying to insert a proxy contract whose fallback function points to the library and I think this is how I would do it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from editing byte code before deploying. you can try doing this on the test net to know what happens with the functionality

Comment: Sure but I am not confident on the consequences of launching nonsense bytecode.. I can be overly cautious. But even if successful I am interested in learning more about why and caveats because I cannot find anything( someone else must have tried). If it fails it could prove nothing and I would again be looking to see if someone else has tried. I think the answer would be useful to other and the caveats or risks if there are any.